# How can I prevent images from css file to be cached?

Tags: php, html, css, caching

How can I prevent `x.jpg` from css file to be cached by browser ?
These images must be refreshed every day.

### CSS file :

```
#slider{
    background: url(1.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat,
                url(2.jpg) 313px 0 no-repeat,
                url(3.jpg) 626px 0 no-repeat,
                url(4.jpg) 939px 0 no-repeat,
                url(5.jpg) 1252px 0 no-repeat,
                url(6.jpg) 1565px 0 no-repeat,
                url(7.jpg) 1878px 0 no-repeat,
                url(8.jpg) 2191px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

I tried this in my php file, but I don't know why it doesn't work :

### PHP file

```
<script>
$("#slider").css(
      "background",
      "url(1.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 0 0 no-repeat,"      +
      "url(2.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 313px 0 no-repeat,"  +
      "url(3.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 626px 0 no-repeat,"  +
      "url(4.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 939px 0 no-repeat,"  +
      "url(5.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 1252px 0 no-repeat," +
      "url(6.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 1565px 0 no-repeat," +
      "url(7.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 1878px 0 no-repeat," +
      "url(8.jpg?v=<?php echo time(); ?>) 2191px 0 no-repeat"
);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you put the jquery code after the #slider element?

Comment: css has no concept of caching. and your PHP timestamps would've been generated *ONCE* when the page was built, then say constant. If you don't want the pics cached, then set them so via server-side configuration.

Comment: after. At the end of my php file.

Comment: I think the code is correct. Can you upload it somewhere so i can see?

Comment: Marc B > Ok, so I think it is a .htaccess trick. I will try.

Comment: Problem actually solved with .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer of my question]

I added this .htaccess file in my image directory :

### .htaccess file

```
<filesMatch "\.(jpg)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```